# Turn off mouse-over for horizontal rule in Vega Lite

Tags: vega-lite

I have the [following code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjKCFIDdkBTAd020gGcAXAJ1gGsjzI6BDeSgBzdqPmqQAvgBpwuSAFteDcsFaxYAG2rIucyCiJKAJiwCkkEVGoBPLsyyQAjgFcOq6m1X5mQ0eLy1bSyxRr0TAAibJQAFuQA2gDsxgCMALrGVHSMRADyPNDIZuQADAB0eQCsyShKSpls2blYeR64UGwAHsiUcp4SqLTIeliIbEqURGKNeEpsAEbaAILwqL75o2OQE9NKAGIIglaStsOwALSUHJSHAMx5eUad41PaWwIAysgAXn5xpbdQaw-bAOpENBhHZQeCwWjSJQ3MYmHK+R6gqT7IhHE6cC5XGErRwI7Yvd7kT7LRqseFERGA4FI8GQwaQTpCcQNKAAEko0DCRGkLBB1C4lAwAHoha5UGwCqgcmFbJMCshYEKOVzpKKiOLDkockRRQAWAoAK0oCGxkB0zjYGngbEkfjNFuEy1WbFMRFoUU6OBW0losiwXthrHMdq18GYJJWyAEbq4ymcdskCFg1AQ4e+eFjUdB8nKvj6YDothGUACaRYJDC2qMJbeHyuTNhLNJuL8AZxRGaSOxgY4nIhLEkvR0iwjpMQ2wHKLRp0x11HEnHz1r5AATHl53hYIhEMNQev01BF9QqagQSxaVCGY355B+HAdFH0P6DwplKp1FhIgeIDniLoDNWQYWCwdgODkzjIK4jrfhQWj-rsRB0Mg0CAWYwFWOCg7WtCDawmASQvs0HR4Quf75va1BpiReBoXalGSLGtD0huEiqLaACq8A5AO2xhOalHdnhkAtG0GgtuQ8A+EoySqNADAAMKwLYAgsOapiAb8ShzAsfj1AeTYrOpz7UYeZEASxNHBiB9gCOBLhUdRwmtO0-pktQvgABrkIcxT1BZJbQIMrZmrA0hRlE65gJ8eQJLh14vnASj9sZjlweRtpISh-lAXamFRsxMGrOq-D5m2JHOusiKTgcxwzpcc4wXclX4suWDEo1cLuX4kkVP5m7bruq77iZXiwCQAAKbA6A+8zkNEBTFDBcVjMtEDLQZ8g+n6UDeCOUB3rAM1PhQRkUPggxFnNxQLe4uEEXgJC9NQERYNEvlOly1JDcNTS2CmlCtRQtHnqm0EZlNR1ibAH5gJcyS+IgoJvckPSnqCK7vVAkzJimkjkMUxQshRoSIS52CdMTHqwvI-F2mua6HHkcSHCuAAcgEZT0KFWAAMlGRBhGwPhgH9yBKAUYCGMkhhYCuABsBk-hRdN5AzTMswAnBziFcywfNhoLwui+LkuATLYBy4T840-GLD03kjPM5c2uZXr-OG0oIuqCbUtQObbOKxQtN26rDvq+ccQu7rvPu0LnvGxLvuQObcQK9bysh2rzNs1HyEsCEYumGAfBwK4tBF0n5vRPNuqBzbAlWPbjua7n3NQAXShFyXsBlxXZtEnE80a3XGeN6HzfO8knN51YHdd0Qpdun30tElcBS1+nwdj1nFyR1POsz+3bCF8XC890vpsr21g8FNEI9b1ATfqxjrcsJcOjF8ooaoKfi-l5fftyAaytt8euKsd7y1flYd+n8KiPl-uff+lcgEgOpqPR+49n7RCgVAGB9A4HzAQb3ABycUH31ttvMO2d2b71dtAvIH98HfyIRfZBWANYrnIQ3DBECta0OjrghhsDmHd2IWwsAGs06gPQZAJ+Ts5xQGnm3SAeCv7wNEaw-u7C76bwoTwqhu8cEqKEUw9RZ8xFaIkazZaCRmQgCEEAA)

which renders fine but it seems to give a mouseover on the dashed line, how do exclude this? Notably it seems to pull the series label from the blue line, not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off the tooltip on the rule mark by setting `tooltip` to `null` in the mark properties:

```
"mark": {"type": "rule", "tooltip": null}
```

See the full chart [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjKCFIDdkBTAd020gGcAXAJ1gGsjzI6BDeSgBzdqPmqQAvgBpwuSAFteDcsFaxYAG2rIucyCiJKAJiwCkkEVGoBPLsyyQAjgFcOq6m1X5mQ0eLy1bSyxRr0TAAibJQAFuQA2gDsxgCMALrGVHSMRADyPNDIZuQADAB0eQCsyShKSpls2blYeR64UGwAHsiUcp4SqLTIeliIbEqURGKNeEpsAEbaAILwqL75o2OQE9NKAGIIglaStsOwALSUHJSHAMx5eUad41PaWwIAysgAXn5xpbdQaw-bAOpENBhHZQeCwWjSJQ3MYmHK+R6gqT7IhHE6cC5XGErRwI7Yvd7kT7LRqseFERGA4FI8GQwaQTpCcQNKAAEko0DCRGkLBB1C4lAwAHoha5UGwCqgcmFbJMCshYEKOVzpKKiOLDkockRRQAWAoAK0oCGxkB0zjYGngbEkfjNFuEy1WbFMRFoUU6OBW0losiwXthrHMdq18GYJJWyAEbq4ymcdskCFg1AQ4e+eFjUdB8nKvj6YDothGUACaRYJDC2qMJbeHyuTNhLNJuL8AZxRGaSOxgY4nIhLEkvR0iwjpMQ2wHKLRp0x11HEnHz1r5AATHl53hYIhEMNQev01BF9QqagQSxaVCGY355B+HAdFH0P6DwplKp1FhIgeIDniLoDNWQYWCwdgODkzjIK4jrfhQWj-rsRB0Mg0CAWYwFWOCg7WtCDawmASQvs0HR4Quf75va1BpiReBoXalGSLGtD0huEiqLaACq8A5AO2xhOalHdnhkAtG0GgtuQ8A+EoySqNADAAMKwLYAgsOapiAb8ShzAsfj1AeTYrOpz7UYeZEASxNHBiB9gCOBLhUdRwmtO0-pktQvgABrkIcxT1BZJbQIMrZmrA0hRlE65gJ8eQJLh14vnASj9sZjlweRtpISh-lAXamFRsxMGrOq-D5m2JHOusiKTgcxwzpcc4wXclX4suWDEo1cLuX4kkVP5m7bruq77iZXiwCQAAKbA6A+8zkNEBTFDBcVjMtEDLQZZVQD6foULRLDeCOJiKCoagSVJBl4HesAzU+FBGRQ+CDEWc3FAt7iMuIBF4CQvTUBEWDRL5TpctSQ3DU0tgppQrW7VZGGptBGZTTdYmwB+YCXMkviIKCgPJD0p6giuQNQJMyYppI5DFMULIUaEiEudgnR0x6sLyPxdprmuhx5HEhwrgAHIBGU9ChVgADJRkQYRsD4YCQ8gSgFGAhjJIYWArgAbBdFAcywXN5DzfMrgAnMLiGiywkthjLcsK0rKuAerYCazT87s-G+t5NzvOYubmVW1LttKPLqgO6rUDO4LOsewJVgG0bFxxP7lsS0Hssh-bysR5AztxNr7sUZz3uG77gsp8hLAhIrphgHwcCuLQtc5870TzbqMdF17PvG2byQi5XVjV0otf17AjfN07RJxPNJud3r8cl4nlwV2LUDD6PRAN26k9q0SVwFB3hcL1ACe++cyf9xbg-r2wNd11v48747e9tTPBTRPPnuLz3-PFKvLBLg6DrsoUMqAH7bybi-SO5ATZu2+LHYuv8tYAKsEAkBFRHwQKflAlusD4Fsy7j-UuxtoioKgOg+gmD5jYIntA3O+Cv5x1PkvMuQsr4BzQXkYBVCwG0OfngrAJsVxMKQSQ-mfctrXzXpAShoCsFjzoYIsAJsC4IKISw3+K8OGpwodwjBfDFECKnkIz+x9v6aPERfchsj9G8IUY-JRJiVEC2WgkZkIAhBAA).